# Delete object by Id using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I'm trying to create API to delete document on mongodb using mongoose.

Here's my route

```
router
    .route("/tasks")
    .delete('/:id', function (res, err) {
        taskSchema.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, tasks) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            const response = {
                message: "Todo successfully deleted",
                id: req.params.id
            };
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        });
    });
```

I get this error

> Error: Route.delete() requires a callback function but got a [object String]

Answer (score 2):

`/tasks` and `/tasks/:id`  are two different routes and you should handle them as such, if you use `/tasks` to display all tasks, make a route for that, and make a second route for every interaction that you already have an ID for; aka deleting, updating, and use the route without the ID for interactions you don't have an ID for, like creating tasks:

```
router
  .route("/tasks")
    .get(/* return all tasks */)
    .post(/* create a task */);

router
  .route("/tasks/:id")
    .delete(function (req, res) {
        taskSchema.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, tasks) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
            const response = {
                message: "Todo successfully deleted",
                id: req.params.id
            };
            return res.status(200).send(response);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Totally Agree!!

Comment: I get the same error even after adding  `/:id` to route

Comment: @HamzaHaddad Right, now it should work, I forgot to remove the extra first argument to the `.delete()`

Comment: I get `req is not defined`

Comment: you should not see that error anymore, you had more problems there than I saw in the first place